# Automatically assign tasks equally based on certain condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

1st table on the left - has total categories for the day.

2nd table from the left (middle) - pre-defined team members who will be responsible for respective category.

Desired output - basically I need to equally allocate categories based on the data from both the tables. But considering they are assigned equally based on 2nd table (middle one).

Answer (score 1):

In `F1` you could use `=A1:A29`

In `G1` you could use `=INDEX(FILTER(D:D,C:C=A1),ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,A1)/(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)/COUNTIF(C:C,A1)),0))`

Bit of an alternative approach requiring office365.

[image]